# Replacing everything with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Currently I have the following structure (the **ID** at the end changes based on the code given by the **shortner**)

```
example.com/7NGOWX
example.com/7iTAXM
```

With javascript I am current using this code to change the url but it leaves the id.

```
<script>
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/example.com/g, '');
</script>
```

How can I make it so that it removes the entire url instead of leaving things like `7NGOWX` `7iTAXM` behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a little regex syntax:

```
example\.com\/\w+
```

- \w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

---

```
<script>
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/example\.com\/\w+/g, '');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex like `/example\.com\/\w+/` , `\w+` match any alphanumerical continuous word.

Answer (score 1):

Another option can be to use the [URL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) constructor and have it do the work.

for example

```js
var url = new URL("http://example.com/7iTAXM");
console.log(url.pathname.substring(1));
```